# is there a way to get all match from tmap to a list

Tags: talend

I'm using Talend to do a joint operation between two tables in order to get all match records.

[image]

Here is my tables:

1. table of Careers
2. table Careers's Interruptions

So the logic is like this one. A person can have a carrer number `X10` witch start form `01-01-2000` to `31-12-2000`.
In the other side, i have multiple interruptions related to this carrer `X10`

- Interruption `X10`  from `01-02-2000` to `05-02-2000`
- Interruption `X10`  from `05-06-2000` to `05-07-2000`
- Interruption `X10`  from `30-10-2000` to `01-11-2000`

I have a function that accept two parameter ( carrer car,  interruption inter )
I use this function to split the carrer interval with the interruption interval
to get only a carrer without interruption

[image]

for example

- carrer start date `01-01-2000`  to `31-12-2000`

with

- interruption   start date `05-02-2000`  to `07-02-2000`

As output function i get this one:

- carrer one :   start date `01-01-2000`  to `04-02-2000`
- interruption:  start date `05-02-2000`  to `07-02-2000`
- carrer two :   start date `08-02-2000`  to `31-12-2000`

  My program work fine, when i have only one interruption related to a carrer.

when i have Multiple interruptions, the function will get all records ( all match rows row by row ) like this

```
carrer X  Interruption I1     ->  to my function ()
carrer X  Interruption I2     ->  to my function ()
carrer X  Interruption I3     ->  to my function ()
```

In this case all the logic will be incorrect as the carrer is not updated after the first split with the first interruption as always we pass the same carrer X 3 time to my function.

My question is is there a way to pass all matches in one shoot to my function 
Like this

```
carrer X ,  List<interruption>  -> to my function
```

Comment: Let me understand this first, 
considering date as a number for example -
let's say - start date is `1` and end date is `100`. 2 Interruptions are present. `20-50` & `40-70`. Should the possible output be - `1-19` & `20-40` & `40-60` & `50-70` & `70-100` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a way to get a list of rows that ( all the interrupt lines that correspond to the main line).
This is done with the [tAggregateRow component.](https://help.talend.com/reader/mjoDghHoMPI0yuyZ83a13Q/yj8JuBj57qWaYoFqIewUiA)

here is the new schema :

[image]

I used two list to group all start DATE and end DATE that much the same carrer.

[image]

and there is my final tmap shcema.

[image]